# Cambiar imagen en ventana JOptionPane

Tags: java, jframe, joptionpane

tengo una duda, ¿Se puede cambiar la imagen verde que sale en la ventana emergente, y si es así, cómo lo hago?[image: Ventana emergente]

En lugar de esa imagen verde con un icono de pregunta me gustaría que tuviera otra

```js
private static void SUMA(){
        Num1=PEDIRNUM1();
        Num2=PEDIRNUM2();
        resultadoProceso= Num1+Num2;
        System.out.print("\n"+resultadoProceso+"\n");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Resultado,"El resultado es: "+resultadoProceso, "RESULTADO", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ese icono ayuda al usuario a identificar el tipo de mensaje que se está mostrando.

Para cambiar el icono puedes cambiar el parámetro '`messageType`' que tiene varias opciones:

```
JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE
JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE
JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE
JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE
JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE
```

Quizás se me pasa alguno.

También puedes agregar un ultimo parámetro que es el '`icon`' con una imagen personalizada.

```
Icon icon = new ImageIcon(".../Desktop/icono.png");
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El mensaje", "Titulo", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, icon);
```